# Which is correct, go for a walk or go to a walk?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I was studying prepositions and stumble upon this phrase "(1) go for a walk (2) go to a walk" which one from these two is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

If the walk is a destination/event (such as a walk to end cancer, a school walk-a-thon, etc.), you could use "go to a walk" or "go to the walk."

However, in most circumstances, "walk" does not represent a destination/event, and you should say "go for a walk."

[This](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/walk) web page might help you out further (Collins Dictionary) by giving you some example sentences.

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case in English, more than one preposition is common and acceptable in an expression with "go...a walk".

I'm going to go on a walk with John.

I'm going to go for a walk this afternoon.

I'm going to go to a walk for senior citizens at the mall (an event).

Also, sentences can use "to walk" (infinitive) rather than a phrase with an indefinite article ("a walk"): "I'm going to walk around the park."